# Cancel the permission for Local notification without Cancelling the scheduled local notification

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am scheduling 64 local notification with different alert body content getting from an array by running a loop..And in my app there is a switch which gives user an option wether he wants to get the notification or not! so basically i want is that when the user turn the switch off the scheduled local notification do not gets cancelled instead of that the registered permission for the local notification gets disabled,so that i do not need to reschedule the notifications again when the user turns the switch On..Is it possible to do so?? if not then what could be the other better way? Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

When your app initially asks for notification permissions, the user's answer (yes or no) is recorded. From that point on only the user can change the permissions and the allowed notification types (alert, sound etc) using the settings app.

The app cannot change permissions itself, all it can do is decide not to schedule notifications (ie. not use the permission that it has)

In your case you will need to cancel any scheduled notifications in order to prevent them being delivered and re-schedule them if the user re-enables notifications.

Comment: Allright and is it possible to remove the notification types such as .Alert and .Sound? @Paulw11

Comment: No, only the user can change the settings once initial permission has been granted (or denied)